# Bootbox and Font awesome icon in button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, bootbox

I'm using bootbox plugin for bootstrap modals.
I would like to know how to put an F.A. icon inside a bootbox dialog button.

This is my code:

```
bootbox.dialog({
        className: "modal-danger nonumpad",
        closeButton: false,
        animate: false,
        title: '...',
        message: "...",
        onEscape: null,
        buttons: {
            refresh: {
                label: "Refresh",
                className: "btn-warning btn-lg pull-left",
                callback: function(){
                    return false;
                }
            },
            main: {
                label: "Setup",
                className: "btn-primary btn-lg",
                callback: function(){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I just need to append inside the bootbox buttons a `<i>` element with a custom class:

```
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can.
`Label` options of button supports HTML, not just text. So

```
bootbox.dialog({
     className: "modal-danger nonumpad",
     closeButton: false,
     animate: false,
     title: '...',
     message: "...",
     onEscape: null,
     buttons: {
          refresh: {
               label: "<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i> Refresh",
               className: "btn-warning btn-lg pull-left",
               callback: function(){
                    return false;
               }      
          }
      }
});
```